# FileInputStream only reads the first word in a file

Tags: java, eclipse, fileinputstream

I want to read words in `file.txt` file token by token and add a Part of Speech tag to each of them and write it to `file2.text` file. `file.txt` content is tokenized. So here's my code.

```
public class PoSTagging {
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
public static void PoStagMethod() throws IOException {

FileInputStream fin= new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\dell\\Desktop\\file.txt");
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fin);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
String strline=br.readLine();
System.out.println(strline+"first");

try{
POSModel model = new POSModelLoader().load(new File("en-pos-maxent.bin"));
PerformanceMonitor perfMon = new PerformanceMonitor(System.err, "sent");
POSTaggerME tagger = new POSTaggerME(model);

String input = strline;
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
ObjectStream<String> lineStream =new PlainTextByLineStream(new StringReader(input));

perfMon.start();
String line;
while ((line = lineStream.read()) != null) {

    String whitespaceTokenizerLine[] = WhitespaceTokenizer.INSTANCE.tokenize(line);
    String[] tags = tagger.tag(whitespaceTokenizerLine);

    POSSample sample = new POSSample(whitespaceTokenizerLine, tags);
    System.out.println(sample.toString()+"second");
    //String t=sample.toString();

    FileOutputStream fout=new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\dell\\Desktop\\file2.txt");
    //fout.write(t.getBytes());

    perfMon.incrementCounter();
    fout.close();
}
perfMon.stopAndPrintFinalResult();
}
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

When `PoStagMethod()` is invoked from another class, only the first word in `file.txt` file gets written into the `file2.txt` file. Why won't it read other words in the file? What is wrong with my code?

Comment: There is only one `br.readLine()` call. You need an "outer loop" around the code you have here, where you read line by line, until EOF.

Comment: Does your file only contains characters and words formatted as text? So why did you bothered yourself with such ambiguous code to read line by line from the `file.txt` ?

Comment: I don't know how PerformanceMonitor and FileOutputStream should work with this read loop. Possibly the use of a Scanner could simplify this considerably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply read the `file.txt` line by line using `BufferedReader`. Then process each line as you know with your `POSModel`, then write the outputs to the `file2.txt` using `BufferedWriter`. A snippet code as below might help:

```
    POSModel model = new POSModelLoader().load(new File("en-pos-maxent.bin"));
    PerformanceMonitor perfMon = new PerformanceMonitor(System.err, "sent");
    POSTaggerME tagger = new POSTaggerME(model);

    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\dell\\Desktop\\file2.txt"));

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\dell\\Desktop\\file.txt"));
    String line = "";
    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
        String whitespaceTokenizerLine[] = WhitespaceTokenizer.INSTANCE.tokenize(line);
        String[] tags = tagger.tag(whitespaceTokenizerLine);
        // Do your work with your tags and tokenized words


        bufferedWriter.write(/* the string which is needed to be written to your output */);
        // for adding new-lines in the output file, uncomment the following line:
        //bufferedWriter.newLine();
    }

    //Do not forget to flush() and close() the streams after your job is done:
    bufferedWriter.flush();
    bufferedWriter.close();
    bufferedReader.close();
```

If you could make this work, it's not bad to replace old-fashioned try-catch clause with **try-with-resource** which was added in java 1.7 to close the resources automatically.

Also If you need to write each word and it's tags in separated lines you may want to have an inner loop for writing to the file. It would be something like below:

```
    POSModel model = new POSModelLoader().load(new File("en-pos-maxent.bin"));
    PerformanceMonitor perfMon = new PerformanceMonitor(System.err, "sent");
    POSTaggerME tagger = new POSTaggerME(model);

    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\dell\\Desktop\\file2.txt"));

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\dell\\Desktop\\file.txt"));
    String line = "";
    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
        String whitespaceTokenizerLine[] = WhitespaceTokenizer.INSTANCE.tokenize(line);
        String[] tags = tagger.tag(whitespaceTokenizerLine);
        for(String word: whitespaceTokenizerLine){

        // Do your work with your tags and tokenized words

        bufferedWriter.write(/* the string which is needed to be written to your output */);
        // for adding new-lines in the output file, uncomment the following line:
        //bufferedWriter.newLine();
        }
    }

    //Do not forget to flush() and close() the streams after your job is done:
    bufferedWriter.flush();
    bufferedWriter.close();
    bufferedReader.close();
```

Hope this would be helpful,

Good Luck.